How to define a custom load shape in Locust for complex user load pattern?
I'm trying to create a complex user load pattern in Locust and need help defining a custom load shape. Here is the scenario I want to implement:
User load pattern:

Ramp-Up to 5000 Users in 2 minutes
Maintain 5000 Users for 1 minute
Ramp-Up to 8000 Users in 5 minutes
Maintain 8000 Users for 3 minutes
Ramp-Up to 12000 Users in 2 minutes
Maintain 12000 Users for 4 minutes
Ramp-Up to 18000 Users in 3 minutes
Maintain 18000 Users for 5 minutes
Ramp-Down to 10000 Users in 5 minutes
Maintain 10000 Users for 5 minutes
Ramp-Up to 20000 Users in 5 minutes
Maintain 20000 Users for 10 minutes
Ramp-Down to 5000 Users in 2 minutes
Maintain 5000 Users for 10 minutes

Total Duration: 1 hour (60 minutes)
I understand that I need to use a custom LoadTestShape class to define this pattern. Could someone explain how to structure the tick method to accurately follow this user load pattern? What would be the best approach to implement this in Locust?

What load shapes have you been able to use so far?
